# ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns when converting python list to dataframe. How to add blank values if 3 passed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list called 'data' that generally has lists with 3 fields but can sometimes have 4:

```
[['Bob', 'DeVito', '100 Lbs'], ['Mac', 'Charles', '150 Lbs']]
```

If I try converting data to a dataframe with at least one of the lists having 4 elements, it will run fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['First', 'Last', 'Weight', 'Height'])
```

but if I run it against the list seen above, it will crash saying

> ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

How can I get it to convert to a df with blank values for the Height column without crashing when I give it a list of lists w/o the 4th column? That way the conversion will run on lists containing only len 3 elems, len 4 elems, or a combo of both .

Desired result:

```
First   Last    Weight  Height
  Bob DeVito   100 Lbs    None
  Mac  Charles 150 Lbs    None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem. First it creates a dictionary from your list elements in a try/ except loop so that if there is no height value isntead of throwing an error it puts np.nan instead. Finally it creates the pandas dataframe from dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list = [['Bob', 'DeVito', '100 Lbs'], ['Mac', 'Charles', '150 Lbs']]
dict = {}
try:
    dict = [{ "First":a[0], "Last":a[1], "Weight":a[2], "Height": a[3]} for a in list]
except:
    dict = [{"First": a[0], "Last": a[1], "Weight": a[2], "Height": np.nan} for a in list]

print(dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)

Output :
   First     Last   Weight  Height
0   Bob   DeVito  100 Lbs     NaN
1   Mac  Charles  150 Lbs     NaN
```

Comment: thanks! i ended up going wtih a try except but without the dictionaries. it tries two seperate dataframe conversions, one with 3 fields and one with 4 :) still clunky but it works